# Trying to bind JS to an html image url- Using WP theme customizer API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

Since I believe this question is more pertaining to Javascript then WP I decided to post it on SO.

I am having a little trouble binding the theme customizer live preview javascript to an HTML `<img src>`- more specifically it is my logo.

Here how the html looks on the page(which is fine and dandy):

```
<a class="footerlogo" href="#top"><img src="<?php echo mytheme_theme_mod( 'footer_logo' ); ?>" /></a> </div>
```

Now my problematic part is the JS - Here are my first two attempts. Both not working.

```
Attempt 1:

    /** Footer logo */
wp.customize( 'mytheme_footer_logo', function( value ) {
    value.bind( function( to ) {
        $( '.footerlogo img src' ).html( to );
    } );
} );
```

Attempt 2:

```
/** Footer logo */
wp.customize( 'mytheme_footer_logo', function( value ) {
    value.bind( function( to ) {
    var footer = $( '.footerlogo img' );

     footer.attr( 'href', to );

    } );
} );
```

Can anyone give me assistance on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the src attribute of the image tag, in jquery you can do this using `attr('src',to)`.

Follow the code above:

```
wp.customize( 'mytheme_footer_logo', function( value ) {
  value.bind( function( to ) {
    var footer = $( '.footerlogo img' );

    footer.attr( 'src', to );
  });
});
```

Comment: I knew I was close. I thought I had even tried this. Apparently not. Thanks alot I really appreciate it.